# how to call a function inside if condition in class component react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a react beginner, and I am trying to call a function in if condition. I want if the condition is true then set the value of a state object to 1 or simply call a function that sets the value to 1.
below is my code:

```
class CountWalls extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            leftcount : 0,
            rightcount : 0
        }
    }
    setright = () =>{ 
         this.setState({rightcount: 1});    
    }
    setleft = () =>{ 
         this.setState({leftcount: 1});
    }
}
    render(){
    const arr = [4, 1, 1, 3, 2];
    let max = 0;
    max = Math.max(...arr);
    if(arr[0] <= max){ this.setleft() }
    if(arr[arr.length - 1] <= max){ this.setright() }  
        return(
            <>
             <h2>Right count: {this.state.rightcount}</h2>
             <h2>Left count: {this.state.leftcount}</h2>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

I am not getting in any trial, just stuck here with the error: Please answer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dt1j.png)
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

If I remove the () parenthesis from function call like this{this.setleft} I get the below error:

src\component\CountWalls.js
Line 21:29:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
Line 22:42:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: The error describes exactly what is going on, you are calling a function such as `setright` in `render` that calls `setState`. Instead just calculate the value for leftcount and rightcount in `componentDidMount`, then call setState once.

Comment: whenever you call a setState, the component is redrawn. So , as you have setRight and setleft inside render(), you are generating an infinite loop. You can use the constructor or componentDidMount to init your data.  https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't update the state in the render method without an HTML event.
otherwise, it will go in an infinite loop

you can use the below code to do so

```
    class CountWalls extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                leftcount : 0,
                rightcount : 0
            }
        }

       componentDidMount(){
            const arr = [4, 1, 1, 2, 3];
            let max = 0;
            max = Math.max(...arr);
            if(arr[0] <= max){  this.setleft() }
            if(arr[arr.Length - 1] <= max){  this.setright() }
            console.log(this.state.rightcount);
        }
        setright = () =>{ 
             this.setState({rightcount: 1});    
        }
        setleft = () =>{ 
             this.setState({leftcount: 1});
        }
        render(){
           
            return(
                <>
                 <h2>Right count: {this.state.rightcount}</h2>
                 <h2>Left count: {this.state.leftcount}</h2>
                </>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: @BhartiPatle welcome. if it is working then please mark my answer as correct

Comment: In continuation to the above code, I have two for loops who are using array values, and i can''t put for loop in componentdidmount. how should I do this?

Comment: I have modified the original code and updated it with for loop logic (complete code)but for loop is not running. left and right count is 1 only as set by setstate